# UIDeviceWhiteColor ctFontRef unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

my app is crashing and showing this error

```
-[UIDeviceWhiteColor ctFontRef]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbd7d892e60
```

i searched lot but did't find any solution

when i am set this attributed text to label

```
 cell.nameLbl.attributedText = [self makeAttributedString:data.userNameStr name:data.nameStr];

-(NSAttributedString*)makeAttributedString : (NSString*)userNameStr name : (NSString *)nameStr
{

NSString *tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[nameStr capitalizedString],[userNameStr lowercaseString]];

NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:tempStr];


[attrStr addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.200 green:0.455 blue:0.749 alpha:1.000]  range:[tempStr rangeOfString:[nameStr capitalizedString]]];
[attrStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.675 green:0.718 blue:0.753 alpha:1.000] range:[tempStr rangeOfString:[userNameStr lowercaseString]]];
[attrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16] range:NSMakeRange(0, tempStr.length)];


return attrStr;

}
```

Comment: i don't know in which line this crashing is occurred
i did't set any property using ctfontref but still crashing

Comment: put breakpoints and check

Comment: Run your code in debug mode and jump over line by line using breakpoint.